# High idle on fuel injected motorcycle

Tags: honda, motorcycle, idle

So my bike has a high idle (gone up as far as 6k revs sometimes). There are no air leaks and the throttle freeplay is fine and cables all nice and free. Clutch is fine also. The fuel lines and injectors should be nice and clean as I have used some redex in the last 2 tanks.
The idle can be fixed by resetting the tps but this only lasts a week and then the problem is back.

The bike is a Honda Grom MSX125. What could be causing this? Cheers.

Comment: How sure are you about the absence of air leaks? Does the engine stall if you cover/seal off the intake?

Comment: I have checked around the intake manifold and exhaust and there doesn't seem to be a change in rpms that would suggest a leak. Also resetting the tps fixes it for a week. There are no error codes suggesting that the tps or other sensors are faulty or malfunctioning.

Comment: If I fully close the air screw it sometimes dies and sometimes keeps running. I know that could suggest a leak but why would it only affect it sometimes? Cheers

Comment: When you close the air screw, does it run when the engine is cold or hot? Also, it might be useful to know which Honda this is

Comment: If I remember correctly it doesn't matter if it's hot or cold ( but mainly tested when cold ). Yes sorry, It is a Honda Grom ( MSX125).

Comment: If you can figure out a pattern to when the engine continues to run vs when it stalls in relation to the engine temp it would confirm if there is an air leak. Other telltale signs of air leaks include hissing, sluggish performance and poorer fuel economy. Could you confirm if any of these are applicable to your bike?

Comment: I was trying to find a pattern but there is no consistency. I can't hear any hissing and the performance seems the same if not better than before. Fuel economy has gone up slightly but I now ride a lot at wide open throttle on the motorway but didn't use to (so would expect it to rise a little). If it cuts out when cold but not hot what would that indicate? The service manual says top end engine problems or air leak would be the casue. What sort of top end problems could cause this as apart from this it runs sweet as a nut. Cheers

Comment: Did this problem get resolved? If so you can post the solution as your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was resolved by replacing the TPS.

Answer (score 0):

Check the throttle body inside maybe you have to clean it check the temperature valve of water  maybe you need a new one
Or you have to fill up some water to the water tank

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a significant leak somewhere. At idle the throttle plate should be almost closed with only a very small gap for mixture to pass through. With this high vacuum there is no way that the engine would rev to 6000 rpm. I would look at the rubber intake manifold and also the throttle body itself to confirm the plate is closing correctly and secure.

Comment: Definatley no air leak. It is very intermittent although resetting the tps sorts it. The tps is also fine though. The issue is definatley electrical related although I understand what you are saying.